# Elasticsearch-Spark has a dependency clash with Play JSON. Error message inside

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-zeppelin, play-json, elasticsearch-spark

I am working on a Zeppelin 0.7.1 and I need to use booth the elasticsearch-spark dependency and the play-json dependency. However these two are for some reason incompatible with each other. If I remove the json dependency, es-spark works fine. The moment I add it, the interpreter breaks.

The following are the interpreters:

`org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.4.1`

`com.typesafe.play:play-json_2.11:2.6.0-M5

(exclude) com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind`

The following is the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:391)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:380)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:146)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:828)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:483)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The excluded jackson-databind is not a problem. Tried it with and without it but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you try 2.10 (scala) version libraries? AFAIK, 0.7.1 was built on JDK8 and scala 2.10

Comment: Yes, I tried 2.10 as well. Nothing changed.

Comment: I am running into the same issue.. except I don't have the Play JSON dependency. Just adding plain elasticsearch-spark makes the spark interpreter stop working. Did you have any luck trying to fix your issue ?

Comment: No. I did not manage to fix this.